# Why does this still work without importing Foundation?

Tags: objective-c, nsobject

Why am I still allowed to use functions and create objects from the `NSObject` class when I didn't import it?

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])  
{  
    @autoreleasepool {  
        NSLog(@"hi");
        NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObject: @"hello"];
        NSLog(@"%@", array);
    }
    return 0;  
}
```

Output

```
2012-08-11 22:15:33.854 prog[1282:403] hi
2012-08-11 22:15:33.857 prog[1282:403] (
    hello
)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most likely you have a Precompiled/Prefix header that imports Foundation, So Foundation gets implicitly added to each header. Look for a file called *-Prefix.pch. Xcode normally puts it in a group called Supporting Files.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to compile with command line by clang, but I failed. I think Xcode does something helps compiling.

```
% cat main.m  

int main (int argc, char *argv[])  
{  
    @autoreleasepool {  
        NSLog(@"hi");
        NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObject: @"hello"];
        NSLog(@"%@", array);
    }
    return 0;  
} 

% clang main.m

main.m:4:9: warning: implicit declaration of function 'NSLog' is invalid in C99
      [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        NSLog(@"hi");
        ^
main.m:5:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'NSArray'
        NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObject: @"hello"];
        ^
main.m:5:18: error: use of undeclared identifier 'array'
        NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObject: @"hello"];
                 ^
main.m:5:27: error: use of undeclared identifier 'NSArray'
        NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObject: @"hello"];
                          ^
main.m:6:22: error: use of undeclared identifier 'array'
        NSLog(@"%@", array);
                     ^
1 warning and 4 errors generated.
```